# Restoring SQL Server database using ADODB retained the database restoring state

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic, database-restore

I'm restoring a database using ASP code (ADODB). The .bak file is in local system. The SQL is local with SQL Authentication.

If I tried the Restore Query in SSMS the restore successful. But the same query in ASP code is not successful. The db will be in Restoring... state.

The Query is

```
RESTORE DATABASE [myDB] FROM  
DISK = N'D:\DB\myDB_20120611_190339.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,  
MOVE N'myDB' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.WEB2K8\MSSQL\DATA\myDB.mdf',  
MOVE N'myDB_log' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.WEB2K8\MSSQL\DATA\myDB_1.ldf',  
NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 10
GO
```

I dont know whats the issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Ganesh.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the WITH RECOVERY option, with your database RESTORE command, to bring your database online as part of the restore process.

Comment: I tried WITH RECOVER too. But no use.


RESTORE DATABASE [myDB] FROM  
DISK = N'D:\DB\myDB_20120611_190339.bak' WITH  RECOVERY, FILE = 1,  
MOVE N'myDB' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.WEB2K8\MSSQL\DATA\myDB.mdf',  
MOVE N'myDB_log' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.WEB2K8\MSSQL\DATA\myDB_1.ldf',  
NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 10
GO

Comment: @Ganesh: The comment is unreadable, please add to your question.